# PHP to remove all non-alphanum characters between two strings

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to remove non-alphanumeric characters from between two strings using PHP.

Input:

> name="K9 Mk. II"
>
> built=2015.06.15
>
> name="Queen Eliz. 3rd (HRH)"

Expected output:

> name="K9MkII"
>
> built=2015.06.15
>
> name="QueenEliz3rdHRH"

My code:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("input.txt");
$contents = preg_replace('/name=\"[^A-Za-z0-9]\"/', "name=\"\\1\"", $contents);
```

Edit: it should only remove unwanted characters from between **name="** and **"**. The line containing **built=2015.06.15** should remain unchanged.

As always, your help is greatly appreciated.

WtS

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: It's not HTML, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Added some more detail showing extra content that the input.txt file may contain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$arr = array('name="K9 Mk. II"','name="Queen Eliz. 3rd (HRH)"');
foreach($arr as $str) {
    $str = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=name=")([^"]+)(?=")/',
        function ($m) {
            return preg_replace("/\W+/", "", $m[1]);
        },
        $str);
    echo $str,"\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
name="K9MkII"
name="QueenEliz3rdHRH"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The regex is cleaner and ignores the data that you want to ignore @Wonko [example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/5757-64i8) +1 Toto

Comment: What a great solution. Thanks to you both for your efforts! You guys rock!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the pattern you're looking for -

```
[^name=\w\"]
```

This excludes 'name=', word characters and whitespace. See it in action [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/dypm-408x)

You can also use the return value instead of actual replacement -

```
$content = preg_replace('/[^name=\w\"]/', '$1', $content);
```

As the `'$1'` will retain the quotes as you need them.

Comment: Thanks Jay. This is VERY close, but a little aggressive in the removal of non-alphanums. I tested this on PhpFiddle using `$a = 'built=2015.06.16\nname="K9 Mk. II"';` and the removed the periods from "2015.06.16". I just need it to remove the unwanted characters from inside name="XXX".

Comment: Ah, so there is additional data that you haven't provided.

Comment: Yes sir! My bad, I thought everyone had mind-reading skills here. :)

Comment: My crystal ball is out for maintenance ;-) Hold on, let me see if I can update.

Comment: `name` in character class doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to first match the names by using: `/name="([a-z0-9]+)"/i` and then calling a function removing the spaces in each match.

Answer (score 0):

$output = preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', '', $InputString);

here i means case-insensitive. 
$InputString is the input you provide. 
$output contains the result we want